# using of "more of"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

When I was reading a text about dreams, I saw this quote. It's the first time I saw "more of" in a sentence so I can't understand the whole sentence. Can someone please help me?

"Dreams are real while they last -- can we say more of life?"

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you about the meaning of the preposition _of?_ What is its ptimary use? What function does _of_ always perform?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To simply state it, the line just means

> Life is no more than a dream

Under the context of the given sentence, the author, Havelock Ellis, quantifies a dream as an event which is real till it lasts. He then also implies that life is also the same and does not differ in a significant way. He asks a leading question *can we say more of life?* with an embedded answer as *"no, we cannot"* to indicate this.